# ¿Porque no carga Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo una consulta, lo que estoy haciendo es metiendo está función de Javascript en un archivo independiente de la página js/script.js pero al meter la función ahí no funciona en la página, si la pego directamente en el documento ya funciona, como le puedo hacer para que funcione en el documento independiente.

Gracias

```js
$('#recipeCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 4000
})

$('.carousel .carousel-item').each(function(){
    var minPerSlide = 3;
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    
    for (var i=0;i<minPerSlide;i++) {
        next=next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
          }
        
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
});
```

Comment: Ya lo solucione, metí la función dentro de  $( document ).ready(function(). Una consulta porque tardan tanto en responder en los foros, disculpen que lo diga pero he tenido mala suerte para que me apoyen ya que casi nunca contestan.

Comment: Hola, para que tengas un mejor alcance en tu pregunta se recomienda sigas estas [recomendaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , de esta forma tu pregunta será mas llamativa para que alguien la responda. Y recuerda que esta comunidad esta para ayudarte, y que hay miles de preguntas por ser respondidas, solo debes ser paciente y seguir investigando

Answer (score 0):

Quizás es un poco tarde, pero deberías ingresar en cualquier parte del HTML `<script src="./script.js"></script>` para que funcione